# Joomla redirect after login

Tags: authentication, redirect, joomla, joomla2.5

I wrote a small authorization plugin (class) for Joomla 2.5 with `onUserAuthenticate` event help. It looks like:

```
class plgauthenticationAuth extends JPlugin{

    public function plgauthenticationAuth($subject, $config){
        parent::__construct($subject,$config);
    }

    public function onUserAuthenticate($credentials, $options, $response){
//my code
```

How from here i can set redirect to custom url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to this

```
$mainframe = JFactory::getApplication();
$redirct = 'your url';
$mainframe->redirect($redirct);
```

Comment: in this case authorization doesn't work. I think i need some ivent like onAfterRoute, but which works after authorization only.